# Where to put Business Logic classes in an Entity Framework - ASP.NET MVC 4 Solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Solution with one project is Entity Framework and have my ASP MVC project, I looking for some advice or opinion about the idea of create in top of my POCO objects and the DBContext, a Business Logic Layer with static classes that have the all the methods (example a ContactBLL class with GetContactByID, GetAllContacts, GetContactsByType) to allow the access to the model data and that can be accessed in the Controllers Actions. In that way I don't have to put the implementation code of this methods in Controller Actions methods, and it can be reusable invoking this methods in other Action Controllers. I will appreciate your opinion because it could guide me to respond a question I've asking to myself around a week based in the answer to this one (about where to define the DBContext and how use it).

Comment: Why use static classes? It will be easier to unit tests non-static classes, especially if they all use interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create different projects according to core functionality.

1. Data Access Layer(DB context and repository etc.)  you can make Project.DataAccess, it will have only db context class and repository.
2. Business Logic Layer(Project.Business) it will have business logic and make call to data access layer.
3. UI Layer(Project.WebUi) it is mvc project.
   and so on.

for detail info you can see this http://prodinner.codeplex.com/ code

Answer (score 2):

1. Create separate class library for your POCO,
2. then create another class library for your repository, this should
   include only the interfaces needed for your repository
3. and the implementation will be on another class lib like Project.EF,
   Project.NH which will include Entity Mapping, Migration, Repository
   implementations. but in reality, chances are you wont be changing
   your ORM lib once it was implemented because it will just cause you
   a lot of headache(just my 2cents).
4. you'll create your business layer(class lib) and
5. web project as separate lib. Models folder of your MVC project will contain your ViewModels.

this is what Im using right now and of course not the best structure, it just something that Im happy with :). hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I will join your recommendations with the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are four standard projects in a ASP.NET MVC - Entity Framework solution. They are 1) MVC, 2) Core/Business Logic Layer(BLL), 3) Data Access Layer/DBContext (DAL) and 4) Common/Utility.

1. Standard MVC project consists three main elements which are Model, View and Controller. However, middle to complex solution usually cuts off the Model element from MVC project and moves it back to BLL, we call it as ViewModel(POCO). Following this structure, MVC project is now responsible for employ/use the services from BLL and control the UI through controller.
2. Business Logic Layer (BLL) is the core of implementing business logic. It is responsible for serving request from the MVC project and work with DAL to persist data. As said above, BLL is the place to define ViewModel, its relations as well interface/ abstract class to support implementing design pattern. Viewmodel(POCO) is likely mapping one-one to data entity at DAL but we do not use the data entity directly on View. Following this structure will help to increase the customization on ViewModel like adding constrains
3. DAL is the place for DBContext and its data entities.
4. Common project consist of shared functions like Logging which is used in 1) 2) and 3)

Please read more at
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70061/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-N-tier-En
https://chsakell.com/2015/02/15/asp-net-mvc-solution-architecture-best-practices/